# Why $-\ell\left(S-L ; \Sigma_O^n\right)+\lambda_n\left(\gamma\|S\|_1+\operatorname{tr}(L)\right) $ is a convex problem

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, parameter-estimation

I read a paper about latent variable graphical models. [*Latent Variable Graphical Model Selection Via Convex Optimization*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1290.pdf).
As stated in this title,
$$
\begin{gathered}
\left(\hat{S}_n, \hat{L}_n\right)=\underset{S, L}{\arg \min }-\ell\left(S-L ; \Sigma_O^n\right)+\lambda_n\left(\gamma\|S\|_1+\operatorname{tr}(L)\right) \\
\text { s.t. } S-L \succ 0, L \succeq 0 
\end{gathered}
$$
is a convex optimization problem.
The log-likelihood function $\ell\left(K ; \Sigma_O^n\right) $ is $$
\ell\left(K ; \Sigma^n\right)=\log \operatorname{det}(K)-\operatorname{tr}\left(K \Sigma^n\right).
$$
I know the graphical lasso is convex，but in the above optimization model, there are two matrix variables that need to be optimized. I have no idea to prove the convexity.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: logdet is concave. Otherwise everything looks to be linear or reducible to linear (needs $\lambda_n\gamma\geq 0$), or a PSD constraint.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I know that, I mean, the log-likelihood function is concave, but when dealing with two matrix variables in an optimization problem, how does it determine whether the optimization problem is convex. Is it fixing a variable and checking if this function is convex for another variable？

Comment: No, it is convex as a function of two variables (or many variables). I don't know how you normally check convexity, but I check that the constraints form a convex set and the epigraph of the objective is a convex set and then the method is the same. You can write this problem in conic form and that is already a proof of convexity. See https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek  I see, what I really want is to prove the function is jointly convex. The function is convex iff its epigraph is convex.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek  I’m not so familiar with this part of the convex optimization and I don't know how to check the epigraph is a convex set in this case.  Would you give me some hints?

Comment: The conic model of logdet appears in the semidefinite section of the cookbook I linked. Everything else you have is already in conic form. So that's it.